# How can i run UDP client and server on two seperate computers?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, localhost

I have a command line program using UDP socket and a UDP hub server running fine on my local host with seperate command prompts. Each the server and the client are bidirectional, so they both need to be able to send and recieve from each other.

I think that all i need to do to make them run on two seperate computers is to change the IP addresses and port numbers respectively. I think i will need to use the private IPV4 address because my socket is UDP IPV4. But i can't confirm because I do not have two different computers. Can someone please reassure me?

For instance, let's say I have basic UDP client and UDP server:

UDP Client is running on a computer with IPV4 162.16.156.1
UDP server is running on a computer with IPV4 162.18.200.1

UDP server should:
- bind to 162.18.200.1
- send to 162.16.156.1
- recieve would happen at 162.18.200.1

UDP client should:
- connect to 162.18.200.1
- send to 162.18.200.1
- recieve would happen at 162.16.156.1

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You have to ensure firewall allows those port for UDP protocol.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a good resource on how to allow UDP ports https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/infinityinstaller/content/installermaster/cofirewalls.htm